# Is there a specific term for someone who works for food and does not get paid?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Someone works in a job where he does not get paid for it but rather just gets meals. Is there a specific term/title for that particular type of work?

Answer (score 1):

If working for *[room and board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_and_board)* is exchanging labor for a place to live and food to eat, then you could say that *working for board* is exchanging labor for food.

[According to Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=work%20for%20board%2C%20work%20for%20room%20and%20board&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), the phrase is not as uncommon as I supposed it might be.

Comment: My accountant wife says being paid with meals is taxable income. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

**Subsistence** may be the answer. As in [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subsistence), it means **the minimum (as of food and shelter) necessary to support life**.

The definition of [European Customs Portal](https://www.tariffnumber.com/info/abbreviations/7344) for **Subsistence worker** can also shed more light.

> Subsistence workers are workers who hold a "self-employment" job and in this capacity produce goods or services which are predominantly consumed by their own household and constitute an important basis for its livelihood.

Also, Not a surprising answer but as introduced in the OP, **[Work for ...](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+for)** is a suitable title.

> *To work in exchange for something, as a sum or salary of money.*
> **e.g.** I offered to work for food and supplies, since they didn't have any money to pay me.

> *To provide labor in exchange for something.* **e.g.** The traveler didn't want any money; he said he would work for food.